# Url Not Found Django

Tags: python, django, templates, view, urlconf

So I'm having a bit of trouble. I get a 404 when I try to visit the url for a certain model:

```
url(r'^rewards/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', RedeemReward.as_view(), name="reward"),
url(r'^rewards/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', CompanyDetail.as_view(), name="company"),
```

So the top url will be something like rewards/amazon-gift card, while the bottom url would be something like rewards/amazon (to show all of the gift cards that amazon has to offer). The reward url works as expected, but I get a 404 when I try to visit the bottom url. The view:

```
class CompanyDetail(DetailView):
    model = Company
    context_object_name = 'company'
    slug_field = 'company_slug'
    template_name = 'asdx/companies.html'

    def get_rewards(self):
    rewards = Reward.objects.filter(company=self.object)
    return rewards

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(CompanyDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['rewards'] = self.get_rewards()
    return context
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your patterns for the two views are identical, so the `CompanyDetail` view can never be called. Instead, the pattern for `RedeemReward` matches all slugs and raises a 404 for slugs that do not match whatever its model class is. (Probably `Reward`.) Put something in the URLs to differentiate company URLs from reward URLs.